# Old Money vs New Money theme

Tags: the-great-gatsby

How does the director portray the differences between "old money" and "new money" in *The Great Gatsby* (2013)?
I have recently read the book and decided to watch the movie as well.
I was trying to interpret the different themes and motifs and how the director portrayed each one of them in the movie.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the 2013 Baz Luhrmann film. Feel free to edit the question if you mean a different one.